# How to make condition for this complicated loop to display value from db only for the first row?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a while loop for matches with rounds:

```
while ( $matches->fetch() ) 

{

echo $round . '.'; //need a condition to only echo round if it is for the first time
echo $team1 . ' VS ' . $team2;

}
```

So, instead of the result e.g.:

```
1.FC BARCELONA VS REAL MADRID
1.MALAGA VS SEVILLA
1.ATLETICO BILBAO VS MADRID
1.MALLORCA VS REAL MADRID
2.FC BARCELONA VS REAL MADRID
2.MALAGA VS SEVILLA
2.ATLETICO BILBAO VS MADRID
2.MALLORCA VS REAL MADRID
```

I need to echo the number of the round only once in the first row like that:

```
1.FC BARCELONA VS REAL MADRID
MALAGA VS SEVILLA
ATLETICO BILBAO VS MADRID
MALLORCA VS REAL MADRID
2.FC BARCELONA VS REAL MADRID
MALAGA VS SEVILLA
ATLETICO BILBAO VS MADRID
MALLORCA VS REAL MADRID
```

How to do that within while loop? I need some if or other condition, but I am out of ideas how to code this, so any help is appreciated.

I have ordered them correctly but need to do the output part now.

Comment: you can get the only one row by the limit 1 in query

Comment: If I use limit 1 in query I get as a result 1 row. I need circa 400 rows. Anyway, I have solved it by using gregmac solution (the winner answer). Take a look there. It's really simple trick how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Track the last round, and only display if it's changed.

```
$lastRound = null;
while ( $matches->fetch() ) 
{
    if ($lastRound != $round) 
    {
        echo $round . '.'; //need a condition to only echo round if it is for the first time
    }
    $lastRound = $round;
    echo $team1 . ' VS ' . $team2;
}
```

Comment: This looks nice . I will try it and let you know in 5 min

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$written = false;
while ( $matches->fetch() ) {
  if(!$written) {
    echo $round . '.'; //need a condition to only echo round if it is for the first time
    $written = true;
  }
  echo $team1 . ' VS ' . $team2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before while define $count = 0; inside while first thing do $count++; and secondly check

```
if ($count == 1) { display round number }
```

Comment: I cannot use that because I have many rounds not just 1. To be exatle between 38 and 42

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;
while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($i == 0)
        echo '1. ';
    echo $row['field'];

    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is

```
$last = null;
while ( $matches->fetch() ) 
{
    ($round !== $last) and print($round . '.');
    echo $team1 . ' VS ' . $team2;
    $last = $round;
}
```